# Powershell is removing comma from program argument

Tags: powershell

I want to pass in a comma separated list of values into a script as part of a single switch.

Here is the program.

```
param(
  [string]$foo
)

Write-Host "[$foo]"
```

Here is the usage example

```
PS> .\inputTest.ps1 -foo one,two,three
```

I would expect the output of this program to be `[one,two,three]` but instead it is returning `[one two three]`. This is a problem because I want to use the commas to deliminate the values.

Why is powershell removing the commas, and what do I need to change in order to preserve them?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The comma is a special symbol in powershell to denote an array separator.

Just put the arguments in quotes:

```
inputTest.ps1 -foo "one, two, three"
```

Alternatively you can 'quote' the comma:

```
inputTest.ps1 -foo one`,two`,three
```

Answer (score 13):

Following choices are available

1. Quotes around all arguments (')

   `inputTest.ps1 -foo 'one,two,three'`
2. Powershell's escape character before each comma (grave-accent (`))

   `` inputTest.ps1 -foo one`,two`,three ``

**Double quotes** around arguments don't change anything !
**Single quotes** eliminate expanding.
**Escape character** (grave-accent) eliminates expanding of next character

Comment: Double quotes seem to have a weird behaviour. If I use them directly in Powershell, they work, but if I launch Powershell with arguments from another program, they do not work.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose it in quotes so it interprets it as one variable, not a comma-separated list of three:

> PS> .\inputTest.ps1 -foo "one,two,three"

Answer (score 3):

if you are passing parameters from a batch file, then enclse your params as below 
"""Param1,Param2,Param3,Param4"""

Answer (score 1):

Powershell will remove the commas and use them to delimitate an array. You can join the array elements back into a string and put a comma between each one.

```
param(
  [string[]]$foo
)
$foo_joined = $foo -join ","
write-host "[$foo_joined]"
```

Any spaces between your arguments will be removed, so this:

`PS> .\inputTest.ps1 -foo one,  two,   three`

will also output: `[one,two,three]`

If you need the spaces you'll need quotes, so do this:

`PS> .\inputTest.ps1 -foo one,"two is a pair","  three"`

if you want to output: `[one,two is a pair,  three]`