# Passing command line arguments to node Cross Platform using different CLI

Tags: node.js, powershell, command-line, cross-platform, command-line-arguments

I'm passing an optional argument to a custom node script via the CLI as follows:

`$ node myscript.js --sizes 10,20,30`

`myscript.js` utilizes [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to capture the `--sizes` list as follows:

```js
if (process.argv.indexOf('--sizes') !== -1) {
    var sizeArgs = process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('--sizes') + 1];
    console.log(sizeArgs); //--> 10,20,30
    // ...
    // using sizeArgs.split(',') later to create an array: ['10','20','30']
    // plus some other logic to validate values are numbers etc etc.
}
```

Desired outcome is that `console.log` prints the string `10,20,30` and that's what correctly happens when running the command *(the one initially shown above)* via:

- Mac OS - using either *Terminal* or *iTerm*
- Mac OSX - using either *Terminal* or *iTerm*
- Windows - using *Command Prompt (cmd.exe)*

---

#### Issue

When running the same command via *Powershell* on Windows `console.log(sizeArgs)` prints `10` only.

So clearly the comma in the string `10,20,30` is somehow being interpreted as another argument, as the following test reveals:

```js
// print process.argv
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```

*Powershell prints:*

> `...`
>
> `2: --sizes`
>
> `3: 10`
>
> `4: 20`
>
> `5: 30`

For environments where the desired outcome is met the following prints:

> `...`
>
> `2: --sizes`
>
> `3: 10,20,30`

---

**Help**

How can this be achieved cross platform considering the quirk in *Powershell*. Ultimately I need to obtain an array of sizes.

The reason I have chosen to use a comma [`,`] as a separator for the `--sizes` string is because another optional argument may also be provided *(`--outdir` which accepts a filepath as a string)*.

**NOTE:** I'm aware there are several package solutions [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs), [args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/args) etc, etc, (which may or may not resolve the *Powershell* issue), however, ***I'm trying to avoid the additional dependency at this stage***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by ensuring `--sizes` value(s) `10,20,30` are put inside double quotes.

As suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990733/1611459).

Therefore a *cross platform* way to pass an argument to `node` that includes a comma(s) is as follows:

`$ node myscript.js --sizes "10,20,30"`

---

**Retest**

Now the test used in the original question prints as follows across all platforms/environments tested:

> `...`
>
> `2: --sizes`
>
> `3: 10,20,30`